# how to setup values for combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I want to setup values for a combobox in vb.net through code. But I don't know what's the code for setting it up. please help.
I want to do something like this:

```
if combobox1.selecteditem="1" then
    combobox2.values=("x", "y", "z")
end if
```

Comment: Be careful; you will add your new set of items to Combo2 EVERYTIME Combo1 comes true... add a Combo2.Items.Clear just before adding the new items to Combo2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the ComboBox.Items collection's Add or AddRange methods.

```
Dim b As ComboBox

' Add them one at a time
b.Items.Add("a")
b.Items.Add("b")
b.Items.Add("c")

' Or in one go
b.Items.AddRange(new string() {"a", "b", "c"})
```